# Fatal error when clone/fetch/pull from shared bare repo in local network

Tags: git

Good day,

I have a trouble with my repository in our local network.

*Bare* repo is placed on my desktop PC in shared folder `git` with path `//my_pc_name/git/MyProject.git`. I can successfully perform `git clone` from my network path below to arbitrary folder in **my PC** and (I use **GitExtentions** software) checkout to the current branches.

1) Instead when my colleges try perform clear `git clone`,  **GitExtentions** gets the following error message:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" clone -v --recurse-submodules --progress //my_pc_name/git/MyProject.git" "D:/my_project_temp"
Cloning into 'D:/my_project_temp'...
done.
fatal: unable to read tree b3b9bc318a0805d071148437a2642eaa0324c809
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry the checkout with 'git checkout -f HEAD'
Done
Press Enter or Esc to close console...
```

The command `status` gives the following message:

```
$ git status
fatal: unable to read tree b3b9bc318a0805d071148437a2642eaa0324c809
```

An attempt to `log`:

```
$ git log --oneline
error: refs/remotes/origin/2222M does not point to a valid object!                                                      09e483a (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Fix API call                                                       error: Could not read 03f460a00faeb915552e2edc1b812ba2d8d31802                                                          fatal: Failed to traverse parents of commit 0a66a7284bb9279d9404d55b1b480a6f28259511
```

2) When try `git fetch` or `git pull` on another machine:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" pull --progress "origin"
fatal: oops (d5d2673a720f6d132938b8d21a124c4284b915a0)
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Done
Press Enter or Esc to close console...
```

and from another one:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" remote update
Fetching origin
fatal: git upload-pack: not our ref 03f460a00faeb915552e2edc1b812ba2d8d31802
error: Could not fetch origin
Done
Press Enter or Esc to close console...
```

3) I tried to create another one *bare* repos by the command from help `git clone -l --bare d:\path_to_local_repo d:\git\shared_repos_path\test.git`. It is Ok, cloning from this new bare repo `git clone d:\git\shared_repos_path\test.git d:\path_to_new_loning_repo`, it'`s Ok, too. But my colleges still could not clone from this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know how I corrupted my repo.

**Solution**: I just share my `.git` local repo with my colleges and its fixed up my problem. And yes, its [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git#Design):

> ...Git gives each developer a local copy of the full development history, and changes are copied from one such repository to another. These changes are imported as added development branches and can be merged in the same way as a locally developed branch.

Best regargs.